# When importing posts to a new site if XML file has postmeta not setup on new server what happens?

Tags: post-meta, import, xml

I have a few XML exports from one domain, and all the posts have postmeta which no longer exists on the new domain. An example is `<wp:post_parent>70</wp:post_parent>` The new domain has no post parents for any post or page.

What happens when I import these XML files. Will WordPress only import data where a custom field or postmeta exists on the new domain for that post type?

Answer (score 0):

wordress core and importer has no way to know how any of the data is actually being used. The importer will just import everything, if a meta data stopped being used then you will get some not needed stuf in your DB but nothing worse then that.

Of course it is very easy to test, just copy your site to a development machine, try to import and check the impact in your specific case.